# rstudio-server permission error after upgrade

Tags: r, file-permissions, rstudio-server

On a VPS with Fedora 23 I recently upgraded my rstudio-server. After this I could no longer login.

After many attempts to repair it I decided to start with a fresh VPS, unfortunately, even here the same problem appears. From `systemctl` I get:

```
ERROR system error 13 (Permission denied); OCCURRED AT:
rstudio::core::Error
rstudio::core::system::launchChildProcess(std::string, std::string, 
rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfig,
rstudio::core::system::ProcessConfigFilter, PidType*)
/root/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/PosixSystem.cpp:1297;
LOGGED FROM: rstu lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

Also:

```
id -u rstudio-server
```

gives

```
993
```

I have also set the minimum user id to 100.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: By any chance are you using PAM for authentication?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for asking. If I understand PAM correctly, this means login in using a standard linux account. If so, yes that is what I am using. Is there an other option?

Comment: Just a note on this, I updated from rstudio-server 0.98.xx to 0.99.xx so there wasn't any change to this I believe.

Comment: PAM is different than standard linux authentication and it requires additional configuration - but probably you don't use it and that is not the issue here.

Comment: You are always typing the commands using root privileges correct?

Comment: ah ok, no I am not using any special form of authentication. I did install everything as root yes.

Comment: @JimRaynor any ideas?